# Cocoa Unmounting drive but not ejecting it

Tags: cocoa, nsworkspace

Do you know you to unmount a drive **without** ejecting it. `NSWorkspace` has some methods to unmount drives but it also eject them.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean physically eject a DVD from the drive?

Comment: No, like with the disk utility. You can Mount/Unmount drives but also eject drives.

Comment: What is the difference (if it is not to physically eject a DVD)?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1545722?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: FWIW the diskutil command has separate 'eject' and 'unmount' options. See `man diskutil`.

Comment: Answer by Vadain on this thread may help you.
[This answer is using dynamic path for your volume or say uses generic way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809658/unmounting-drive-volume-without-ejecting/34810198#34810198)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing it as follows and it un-mounts the drive but doesn't eject it.

(Actually I want to eject the disk, I can only un-mount the disk. :P Please share how to eject a disk.)

```
DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

CFURLRef path = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, CFSTR("<path_to_your_volume_here>"), NULL);
DADiskRef disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, path);

DADiskUnmount(disk, kDADiskUnmountOptionDefault, __unmountCallback, NULL);
```

This is the code I am still working on and is under development and testing.
I am creating the "path" manually. You can use (and share) a better method to get the path of volume in a generic way. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409675/1082289) has hints of doing it the right way.

I'll update when my development is refined and complete.

Comment: Works great. Just had to add the DiskArbitration FrameWork in XCode and in the headfile. And to eject the disk I use : `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] unmountAndEjectDeviceAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:device.path] error:&error];`

Answer (score 2):

To do this, use DADiskUnmount in DiskArbitration framework.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/DiskArbitration_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DADiskUnmount

Answer (score 1):

To eject the disk, unmount the disk as you stated, and then in your __unmountCallback do the following:

```
            DADiskRef disk2 = DADiskCopyWholeDisk(disk);
            DADiskEject(disk2,
                        kDADiskEjectOptionDefault,
                        NULL,
                        NULL);
```

You can pass any object as context to the DADiskUnmount() and then, for example, use it to determine if the respective disk should be ejected in the __unmountCallback.